# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to call web API using spring-boot and webclient. web api is of graph ql. so I am passing parameters using JsonObject as following.

```
JSONObject variables = new JSONObject();
JSONObject docParam = new JSONObject();
try {
    docParam.put("id", 0);
    docParam.put("name", metadata.get("resourceName"));
    docParam.put("type", metadata.get("Content-Type"));
    docParam.put("datasourceId", 5);

    variables.put("document", docParam);
} catch (Exception e) {
}

LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
formData.add("query", "mutation ($document: Document, $projectId: Int!) { addDocument { id } }");
formData.add("variables", variables);

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("https://localhost:44375/api/graph")
                                    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();

webClient.post().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).syncBody(formData).retrieve()
                                    .bodyToMono(String.class).subscribe(response -> {
                                        Extract.saveProcessedFile(response);
                                    });
```

I am getting following error when webclient call is sent.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap["variables"]->java.util.LinkedList[0])
```

Comment: You have mentioned JSONObject variables = new JSONObject(); and formData.add("variables", variables);. It means variables contains no information.

Comment: variables.put("document", docParam);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting `JSONObject` to `JsonObject` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue if you look into the following discussion which is exactly matching your scenario.

https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit/issues/41

To quote below,

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No
>   serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties
>   discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
>
> When using like
>
> JSONObject object = new JSONObject(); object.put("abx","xyz");
>   JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject(); object1.put("qwe","rty");
>   CustomMatcher.assertThat(object, JsonMatchers.jsonEquals(object1));

Lucas mentioned that it should be fixed as per the below statement.

> Thanks for feedback. Should be fixed in 1.14.1

I know that it may not resolve your problem, it is for your reference. Hopefully you can use higher version for trial.

Comment: I added following in my gradle dependency. still same error.
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9'
 compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.9'
 compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9'